# GameKit's sendDataToAllPeers isn't sending packets quick enough

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, bluetooth

I'm trying to send files over a bluetooth connection.

I've got this to work thanks to my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837102/send-and-receive-nsdata-via-gamekit), but the method wasn't memory efficient.

The whole file was loaded into memory before it was sent, and this created problems (and crashed the app) for files > ~20 MB. So I've come up with a new method of only reading parts of the file I need at a specific time, creating packets from the data, sending them and repeating the process for each 8KB chunk of the file.

So I made a class method that generates the packet, informs the controller that a packet is available (through a protocol) and repeats this process for each packet that's available.

Here's the code for the packet generator:

```
+ (void)makePacketsFromFile:(NSString *)path withDelegate:(id <filePacketDelegate>)aDelegate {
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path] || aDelegate == nil) return;

    id <filePacketDelegate> delegate;
    delegate = aDelegate;

    const NSUInteger quanta = 8192;
    uint filesize;

    NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:path error:nil];
    filesize = [[fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSize] intValue];

    int numOfPackets = (int)ceil(filesize/quanta);
    if (numOfPackets == 0) numOfPackets = 1;

    NSLog(@"filesize = %d, numOfPackets = %d or %.3f", filesize, numOfPackets, (float)ceil(filesize/quanta));

    NSFileHandle *handle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:path];

    int offset = 0;
    int counter = 0;

    while (counter != (numOfPackets + 1)) {
        uint len = (filesize < quanta) ? filesize : quanta;
        if (counter == numOfPackets) {
            len = filesize - offset;
        }
        [handle seekToFileOffset:offset];
        NSData *fileData = [handle readDataOfLength:len];
        file_packet *packet = [[file_packet alloc] initWithFileName:[path lastPathComponent] ofType:0 index:counter];

        packet.packetContents = fileData;
        [fileData release];
        packet.checksum = @"<to be done>";
        packet.numberOfPackets = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", numOfPackets];

        [delegate packetIsReadyForSending:packet];

        [packet release];

        offset += quanta;
        counter++;
    }

    [handle closeFile];

}
```

And receiving and sending the file:

```
- (void)packetIsReadyForSending:(file_packet *)packet {
    NSData *fileData = [packet dataForSending];
    [self.connectionSession sendDataToAllPeers:fileData withDataMode:GKSendDataReliable error:nil];
}

- (void)sendFileViaBluetooth {
    [file_packet makePacketsFromFile:selectedFilePath withDelegate:self];
}
```

However, the memory use is quite large. Not what I expected.

I'm a bit stuck on this, as I wouldn't like to restrict bluetooth sharing to files smaller than 20MB.

Any help appreciated.

**Edit:**
I've been thinking about this for a while and have come to the conclusion that it's not my code that's causing the memory allocation issue, it's GameKit's stack for sending the packets.

I think I'm generating too many packets too fast, and I don't think GameKit is sending them quick enough.

So I am now thinking about a way to see when GameKit has sent a packet, and only generating another one once GameKit confirms it was sent.

Answer (score 2):

There’s one clear memory management issue in your code:

```
NSData *fileData = [handle readDataOfLength:len];
```

`fileData` wasn’t obtained via NARC (a method whose name contains new, alloc, retain, copy), so you don’t own it, hence you don’t release it.

```
[fileData release];
```

Oops.

As for the memory use, one thing to consider is that even though you release `packet` you can’t really tell what’s going on inside `-[GKSession sendDataToAllPeers:withDataMode:error:]`. It is possible that the method internally creates autoreleased objects that only end up being released after `+makePacketsFromFile:withDelegate:` has finished executing. I suggest you use a new autorelease pool in every loop iteration:

```
while (counter != (numOfPackets + 1)) {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [NSAutoreleasePool new];

    uint len = (filesize < quanta) ? filesize : quanta;
    …
    counter++;

    [pool drain];
}
```

By doing this, any autoreleased object inside that loop will be effectively released at the end of each loop iteration.

Comment: Sadly, memory usage is sky-high. I'm not sure what's allocating all of this memory, this is becoming a bit annoying.

Comment: @Jack Do you release your instance variables/set your declared properties to `nil` in `-[file_packet dealloc]`?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the [NSInputStream](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInputStream_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  With it you can open a stream and only read out a buffer of bytes at a time.