# How to pack struct in NSData?

Tags: objective-c, nsdata

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Send and receive NSData via GameKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837102/send-and-receive-nsdata-via-gamekit)

I have struct which consists of int variable and 2 float pointers (arrays). How can I pack this struct ib NSData and later unpack it?

Comment: Use [`dataWithBytes`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSData/dataWithBytes:length:) and supply `(const void *) &struct_data` and `sizeof struct_data`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can pack the structure using dataWithBytes method pf NSData :

```
struct aStruct {
/* Implementation */
};

//Struct variable 
aStruct exampleStruct;

// pack the struct into an NSData Object
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithBytes:&exampleStruct length:sizeof(exampleStruct)];

// get back the the struct from the object
[myData getBytes:&exampleStruct length:sizeof(exampleStruct)];
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you also show is there are  float*x and float*y in struct how to initialize them,add numbers and later get them from unpacked struct? Coz my realisation doesnt work and i get another numbers in arrays,not that I put into

Comment: @ValentinKhrulkov if these structs represent data that needs to be serialized and persisted outside of the context of the running application then I don't think it will work well for you to have pointers inside of them.

Comment: @Carl Veazey nono,inside app,just how to do it?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is it possible to save this data to disk afterwards?